# Condition fails while check for thread IsAlive or null in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am developing one small excel application, in that i am using 3 threads reading some function. Its not necessary that all threads are invoked to read particular function, based on checkbox selection , particular thread will run.

Threads i defined under global part as listed below.

```
 Thread Run_thread = null, Run_thread1 = null, Run_thread2 = null;
```

/* calling of threads based on checkbox selection*/

```
     if ((checkBox1.Checked == true) && (textBox2.Text != ""))
                {
                    Run_thread = new Thread(() => READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHS(textBox2.Text, 5, 15));
                    Run_thread.Start();
                    check++;
                }
                if ((checkBox2.Checked == true) && (textBox5.Text != ""))
                {
                    Run_thread1 = new Thread(() => READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHS(textBox5.Text, 7, 9));
                    Run_thread1.Start();
                    check++;
                }
                if ((checkBox3.Checked == true) && (textBox6.Text != ""))
                {
                    Run_thread2 = new Thread(() => READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHS(textBox6.Text, 5, 15));
                    Run_thread2.Start();
                    check++;
                }
```

now if user selects checkbox 1 and checkbox2 then Run_thread1 and Run_thread will be in IsAlive state and Run_thread2 will have null;

now checking thread is alive or not

```
    if (!(Run_thread.IsAlive || Run_thread1.IsAlive || Run_thread2.IsAlive))
                    {
                      //do something
                    }

                   else
                    {
                             //message thread are in running mode.
                     }
```

in above check error is coming when Run_thread2 is checked for status

```
 "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

can some one help me in fixing this issue. I am new to thread.

Comment: Start from [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously some fields will be `null` if you do not create instances, which you do based on the corresponding checkboxes.

Try this:

```
if (!(Run_thread != null && Run_Thread.IsAlive ||
     Run_thread1 != null && Run_thread1.IsAlive ||
     Run_thread2 != null && Run_thread2.IsAlive))
```

Comment: its not working for third condition  ..is there is some way to initialize thread other than null value..

Comment: Can you explain a little more than 'its not working'?

Comment: Sanjeev Kumar please have a look at this course, it is absolutely free https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169?l=LK8n0uQIC_306218949

Comment: actually what i want is if i run check condition, it should check any of the thread is running or not...if none of them are running then go head perform activity.. but this condition allowing it to do its activity even threads are running..

Comment: some silly mistake is there but unable to figure it out

Comment: @SanjeevKumar I think the condition is checking that. The current check is `not (any thread alive)` which translate to `no thread alive`.

Comment: by using this condition i am trying to check if none of them are alive then do somethings else not.. (keeping not condition at start)

 if (!(Run_thread.IsAlive || Run_thread1.IsAlive || Run_thread2.IsAlive))

Comment: thanks Maarten  , i modified the condition and it worked....